# Python : is there a shortcut for pattern [sth = get_sth() ; if sth: do_a_thing_on(sth)]

Tags: python

HI !

I guess everything is in the question ...
I was just wondering if there is a nice way in Python to shorten this pattern :

```
something = get_something()
if something:
    do_a_thing_with(something)
```

Meaning that I would like  to enter in the `if` context only if the variable `something` is not None (or False), and then in this context having this variable set automatically ! Is it possible with `with` statement ?

PS : I don't want to have to DEFINE more stuff... I am looking for some statement to use on the fly ?!

Comment: is this not short enough for you?

Comment: I could save one line :)

Comment: @sebpiq: Completely forgot about that. Yeah.

Comment: -1: No one wins at Code Golf.

Comment: >:-( Thanks for the Python lesson ... But that's not the point here I guess

Comment: "PS : I don't want to have to DEFINE more stuff"  What does this mean?  First, you only define functions and classes in Python.  You have two functions and a variable.  What **more** could possibly be involved in this?  What's this mysterious *more* that you're worried about?  Any specific problem or concern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is as pythonic as it gets.**

Things should be no more simplified than they are and no more complex than they should be.

See how the with statement works and providing a context guard. would be complicated enough.

- http://effbot.org/pyref/with.htm
- http://effbot.org/pyref/context-managers.htm

Comment: Which means that I could use it for this, but I would have to create a ugly hacky context manager... right ? Hmmm ... I was just wondering if there is something standard, because it is a pattern that is very very frequent in my code !

Comment: Yeah ok ... So no readability sacrifices for saving one line of code today :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pattern that is very frequent in your code (as you suggested in a comment to @pyfunc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031106/python-is-there-a-shortcut-for-pattern-sth-get-sth-if-sth-do-a-thing-on/4031138#4031138)), you can just make it a function:

```
def safeProcessData(getData, handleData):
    buffer = getData()
    if buffer:
        handleData(buffer)
```

In this case the parameters `getData` and `handleData` would be callables, meaning any function (free or member) and objects that implement `__call__`.

Comment: Yeah that's a good way to do it, but I was just wondering if there is a standard way... like a statement I am not aware of, or something. But looks there ain't !

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your existing code is already nice and short... If you really want a one-liner, try a list comprehension:

```
[do_a_thing_with(something) for something in [get_something()] if something]
```

Comment: Wow ! That's a good one ! But actually I don't really want to sacrifice readability.

Comment: If do_a_thing_with() returns a value you should add `[0]` to the end to get a single value not a list. I'm ashamed to admit I thought of this hideous way of doing it as well!